# Percentage plot from pandas based on two coulmns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

**Data**

```
 List=['X','Y'] 

ColA  ColB  ColC   

te     Y    a
te     Y    a
alo         a
te     Y    b
te     2    b
bb     Y    b
aa     X    c
alo    u    c
aa     b    c
```

I want to plot a bar diagram with col A on x-axis and percentage of values having any value from list in the col B for example for  te (3/4)*100, aa(1/1)*100, alo(0/1)*100 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner can be

```
df.groupby('ColA').ColB.apply(lambda x: x.notna().sum()/len(x)).mul(100).plot(kind='bar')
```

Data provided

```
  ColA  ColB
0   te     Y
1   te     Y
2  alo  None
3   te     Y
4   te  None
5   bb     Y
6   aa     X
```

Note: Don't forget to import matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Output

[image]

Comment: in Col B I have many values and want to consider only which are in the `List`

Comment: Apply a filter and then use the above code like `df = df[df.ColB.isin(List)]`